# Formatting columns in a dataframe including widgets with DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to format a dataframe rendered by DT (adding color to specifics columns, changing the font, ...), and I was thinking about using the format functions available in DT (i.e. `formatStyle`, `formatCurrency`).

However, these functions can only be used on a datatable, and I cannot convert my dataframe to a datatable, as it breaks the different widgets I have inserted in specific columns.

```
library(shiny)

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
  }
  inputs
}

df <- iris

df$hist <- shinyInput(actionButton, nrow(df), "hist_", label = "Hist", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' )
df$num <- shinyInput(numericInput, nrow(df), "num_", label = NULL, value=NULL)

ui <- dashboardBody(box(fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('DTdf'))))

server <- function(input, output){
  dfDT <- reactive({df})
  output$DTdf <- DT::renderDT(
    dfDT(),  
    escape=F,
    options = list(
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I tried to replace the first argument of the `renderDT` function like this, but the widgets stop working.

```
output$DTdf <- DT::renderDT(
    datatable(dfDT()),  
    escape=F,
    options = list(
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
```

One solution I found to format the columns would be to directly change their content with HTML code, for example if I wanted to changed the fond of the species to bold:

```
df$Species <- paste0("<div><b>", df$Species, "</b></div>")
```

But that causes a lot of issues in my program, I'm looking for a solution to only change the visual aspect of the `DToutput`, not the data in my dataframe.

Comment: That should work. Normally one puts the arguments `escape` and `options` inside the `datatable` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output){
  dfDT <- reactive({df})

  output$DTdf <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(dfDT(),
    escape=F,
    options = list(
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))) })
}
```